# ifstream is crashing on x64 bit platform

Tags: c++, file, 64-bit, ifstream

i am trying to use `ifstream` to open a txt file and read data from that file with `ifstream`, while that code works just fine on x86 bit platform, it causing weird application crash when using it on x64 bit platform.

```
ifstream font;

font.open(filename);
if ( font.fail() )
{
    return false;
}

// Used to read 95 ASCII characters in the text file
for ( int i = 0; i < 95; i++ )
{
        font.get(temp);
        while (temp != ' ')
        {
            font.get(temp);
        }

        font.get(temp);
        while (temp != ' ')
        {
            font.get(temp);
        }

        font >> m_Font[i].left;
        font >> m_Font[i].right;

        font >> m_Font[i].size;
}
```

Removing `font.fail()` check causes the program to be stuck at `font.get(temp);` which means that `font.fail()` is causing the crash of the program, if someone knows a solution to this problem or can point to an alternate way of reading the text file in this context please let me know.

The reproducible example can be found below, make sure to set the build configuration to x64 and subsystem to Windows`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct TestStruct
{
    int test;
}; TestStruct* testStruct;

bool Test(char* filename)
{
    testStruct = new TestStruct[8];
    if (!testStruct)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ifstream font;
    font.open(filename);
    if (font.fail())
    {
        return false;
    }

    char temp;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        font.get(temp);
        while (temp != ' ')
        {
            font.get(temp);
        }

        font.get(temp);
        while (temp != ' ')
        {
            font.get(temp);
        }

        font >> testStruct[i].test;
    }

    font.close();

    return true;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pScmdline, int iCmdshow)
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    
    while ( Test((char*)"test.txt") )
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S I am failing to reproduce this issue while executing binary by itself from build folder however it still occurs while launching it with local windows debugger attached.

Comment: Does `font.fail` really *crash*, or does this function `return false` and then something else goes wrong?

Comment: Well, the problem as described above is that `font.fail()` is causing the crash problem which suggests that the file is not only not being opened but also check if it was opened or not is not working correctly on the 64-bit platform.

Comment: It never goes to the `return false` the crash happens before that but after `font.open`

Comment: As for `for ( int i; i < 95; i++ )` i do initialize `i` above, i just reformated code here for the sake of simplicity, will edit it not to confuse anyone though

Comment: Please post a [mre]. It should compile and reproduce your problem.

Comment: How are`m_Font` and `temp` declared?

Comment: There is nothing specific to 64 bit for why this would not work. I have used 64 bit for 15+ years now.

Comment: `(char*)"test.txt"` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: I am trying to see if I can reproduce the error in Visual Studio.

Comment: To answer a question about what i saw in the debugger, not much if i don't place any breakpoints, if i place them though then it last thing it stopped at was `font.fail()` and after that application has crashed.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in x64 debug mode in Visual Studio 2019. The ` while ( Test((char*)"test.txt") )` loop is infinite so the function keeps loading the test.txt file I put in the same folder as the project.

Comment: Well, that's weird, to explain what i am trying to achieve is, i am making my custom rendering engine with DirectX 11 and for this specific thing i followed [this](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut12.html) example on rastertek, literally downloading visual studio project provided and changing architecture to x64 made me reproduce that same error successfully (In case of this tutorial it will throw a message box with an error regarding font not being found, and crash the problem after that)

Comment: why don't use `bool Test(const char* filename)`? Casting like this `(char*)"test.txt")` invokes UB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as some pointed out, casting from one string type to another type, in this case from `const char*` to `char*` is causing undefined behavior, at first i fixed it in the reproducible example but couldn't fix it in my main project but after changing all string types to the ones that original function is taking it solved the problem, i.e:

`D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile` is taking `LPCTSTR` and caused a crash while i was trying to cast `LPCTSTR` from `WCHAR*`

Comment: My advice is if you have to cast a pointer to a string type you are most likely making a mistake because the cast does not transform the data pointed to the other type it just silences the compiler.

Comment: `LPCTSTR` means *long pointer to const string* which is `const char*`. And why are you passing a `wchar_t*` to `const char*`?

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop that calls the same function with the same parameter. This function does exactly the same procedure but has a side effect of creating an array of `TestStruct`.

When everything "goes ok", the function returns true, and is called again. One problem is that you never delete the array you are dynamically creating inside of the function. That means that sooner or later you would run out of memory, and this infinite loop would be broken. But it wouldn't be broken in the way you plan it: the `operator new` (the one that you are using) would throw an exception (`std::bad_alloc`) instead of returning `nullptr`.

That is what I see from your code. The compiler may see the same, and it can optimize the code in many strange ways to achieve the same behavior. Try to correct the issues that cause the UB and memory leaks, and maybe the compiler would change it's mind.